# bash script - trying to concatenate two strings - failing

Tags: bash

I want to write a script that takes the current folder name and adds the postfix _default to it at the end.

My script so far looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
baseDir=pwd | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
networkName=$(baseDir)$('_default')

echo $networkName
```

When I run this i get the following errors:

```
codebrews@mymachine:/docker-local$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 3: baseDir: command not found
./test.sh: line 3: _default: command not found
```

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm messing up but I can't see it.
Thanks.

EDIT 1

I also tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
baseDir=pwd | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
networkName=$($baseDir)_default
echo $networkName
```

But that just returns

_default

I see now that the problem is basedDir is blank.
When I run "pwd | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'" on the command line it works.
But its clearly not working in this script file.

Comment: Do you really need a script for this? All you want is `echo "$PWD"_default`.

Comment: Only a small one, as I believe OP only wants the `pwd`'s name rather than the entire path.

Comment: You'll find https://shellcheck.net/ immensely useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
baseDir=pwd | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

This command will assign the variable `baseDir` to the string `pwd`, and then pipe the output of that assignation (i. e. nothing) into `awk`, which will do nothing.

```
networkName=$(baseDir)$('_default')
```

This command will attempt to assign the variable `networkName` to the output of the command `baseDir` (which does not exist, hence the first error) concatenated to the output of the command `'_default')` (which does not exist, hence the second error).

```
echo $networkName
```

Because the previous command did not work, this would output nothing other than the terminating newline.

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
baseDir="$(pwd | awk -F/ '{print $NF}')"
networkName="${baseDir}_default"

echo "$networkName"
```

Comment: Or `printf "%s\n" "$(basename "$PWD")_default"`, but I appreciate you were trying to remain with the idiom of the OP